# Apache camel ftp component - notification on successful transfer

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-ftp

We are in the process of building a Java application with Camel to transfer files between two FTP locations. Is there a way to get a notification on the successful transfer of a file? We are not allowed to use a JMS solution for building the application.

Comment: You can have multiple `to` calls in a route. I don't know what notification mechanism you have in mind... if not JMS, then a web call, perhaps? `.to("ftp:...").to("http:...")` Or perhaps you want it to send an email? `.to("ftp:...").to("smtp:...")` Or maybe you want to use a SEDA event `.to("ftp:...").to("seda:...")`. I think you get the point.

Comment: @Ray Thanks for the quick reply. To add some clarity, the total flow would include
1. Read from remote FTP a location, on successful read rename it and move it to a different folder
2. Add wiretap to do some processing
3. Write the file in to a different remote FTP location. 

Is it possible to get a status notification on successful writing/transfer?

Comment: I know you need this notification for business reasons. Do you need this to be communicated to comeone or just log it. What are you doing with the notification of completion. Your answer for this would help us to enhance the answers we try to give

Comment: @NaveenRaj Yes naveen, I need to keep a track for all the successful transfers. This need to be achieved without using any JMS solution. Just logging may not suffice for me. I ideally I'm looking for some kind of success flag from the target FTP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you could create another route and have seda/vm as the endpoint.This endpoint needs to be called after the ftp endpoint.

```
<route id="MainRoute">
<from uri="ftp:RemoteLocation"/> 
<from uri="seda:Retry"/>
<to uri="seda:MyLog"/>
<!--Your Main Processing logic -->
</route>

<route id="Notification-processor">
<from uri="seda:MyLog"/>
<!--Your Logging/Notification Processing logic -->
</route>
```

In the above scenario of Notification-processor you can have your custom notificaiton/log activity. This is your custom notification logic. If you need to notify for anomalies you can have a to endpoint in the Notification-processor for sending the notification.

You need to write logic to check if the message is complete if not you can have a bean called in the Notification-processor which can have dynamic route to extract the specific file form the ftp location and reprocess it. Like below

```
<route id="Notification-processor">
<from uri="seda:MyLog"/>
<!--Anomaly checker  -->
<to uri="seda:Retry"/>
<!--Your Logging/Notification Processing logic -->
</route>
```